# Adding existing data to SVN server-side repository

Tags: centos, repository, subversion

I have a CentOS 7-based SVN server. Is there a way to create a repository over existing data? The server is based in `/home/server`. I need this folder to become an SVN repository, so my friends and I can edit everything straight on the production server with no need to copy it from the repository directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a repository over existing data?

Yes, *to some extend** (you can't without move-tricks get repo on already existing dir, but can create repository and have "existing data" as starting point of history)

> I need this folder to become an SVN repository

No, **you don't want it**, because SVN-repository isn't just mirror of real tree, it's **database**, which contain real-tree and history of changes, but physically folder-tree of repository isn't tree of content.

You *may* want to convert this folder to **Working Copy of repository**

> so my friends and I can edit everything straight on the production server with no need to copy it from the repository directory.

Why not?! Just, instead of "copy it from the repository directory" you all have don't to forget commit changes, when they are done